# Magento 2.2.5 | How to redirect page to payment gateway provider after clicking on place order, Custom Payment Gateway Module

Tags: magento-2.2.5

I am new to Magento 2 Platform and this my first project, I have some basic knowledge about Magento.

I am creating a custom payment method module and achieve the front end part means I can see the UI on admin and checkout also.

**Steps I take.**

1. Created a block

   ```
        class Main extends  \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
          {
           protected $_objectmanager;
          protected $checkoutSession;
          protected $orderFactory;
          protected $urlBuilder;
           private $logger;
          protected $response;
            protected $config;
           protected $messageManager;
          protected $transactionBuilder;
       protected $inbox;
          public function __construct(Context $context,
                           Session $checkoutSession,
                           OrderFactory $orderFactory,
                           Logger $logger,
                           Http $response,
                           TransactionBuilder $tb,
                           \Magento\AdminNotification\Model\Inbox $inbox
                          ) {


   $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
   $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
   $this->response = $response;
   $this->config = $context->getScopeConfig();
   $this->transactionBuilder = $tb;
   $this->logger = $logger;
   $this->inbox = $inbox;

   $this->urlBuilder = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
       ->get('Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');
   parent::__construct($context);
       }

         public function _prepareLayout()
            {
           $method_data = array();
            $orderId = $this->checkoutSession->getLastOrderId();
            $this->logger->info('Creating Order for orderId $orderId == '.$orderId);
            $order = $this->orderFactory->create()->load($orderId);
          if ($order)
                  {
                $billing = $order->getBillingAddress(); //get billing address
       $payment = $order->getPayment();
       $payment->setTransactionId("-1");
       $payment->setAdditionalInformation(
           [\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Transaction::RAW_DETAILS => array("Transaction is yet to complete")]
       );
       $trn = $payment->addTransaction(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Transaction::TYPE_CAPTURE,null,true);
       $trn->setIsClosed(0)->save();
       $payment->addTransactionCommentsToOrder(
           $trn,
           "The transaction is yet to complete."
       );
       $payment->setParentTransactionId(null);
       $payment->save();
       $order->save();
       try{
           $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
           $client_id = $this->config->getValue("payment/ndhk_pg/client_login",$storeScope);
           $client_secret = $this->config->getValue("payment/ndhk_pg/client_pass",$storeScope);
           $testmode = $this->config->getValue("payment/ndhk_pg/ndhk_testmode",$storeScope);
           $this->logger->info("Client ID: $client_id | Client Secret : $client_secret | Testmode: $testmode");
           $api_data['txnid'] = time() ."-". $order->getRealOrderId();
           $api_data['login'] = $client_id;
           $api_data['pass'] = $client_secret;
           $api_data['amt'] = round((int)$order->getGrandTotal(),2);
           $api_data['txncurr'] = "INR";
           $api_data['date'] = "INR";
           $string = $client_id.$client_secret.$api_data['txnid'].$order->getGrandTotal().$api_data['txncurr'];
           $hashkey = hash_hmac('sha512', $string, '35d97d4459ae1883cbd2bb8be644115');
           $api_data['signature'] =  $hashkey;
           $api_data['date'] = date('d/m/Y H:m');
           $api_data['mobile'] = "8446320942";
           $api_data['od'] = "Order Description";
           $api_data['ru'] = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl("ndhk/response");
           $this->logger->info("Date sent for creating order ".print_r($api_data,true));
           if($testmode){
               $api_data['actionUrl']  = "https://sandbox.abcpay.com/abc_Api/paymentRequest";
           }else{
               $api_data['actionUrl']  = "https://prod.abcpay.com/abc_Api/paymentRequest";
           }

           return $api_data;


       }catch(\CurlException $e){
           // handle exception related to connection to the sever
           $this->logger->info((string)$e);
           $method_data['errors'][] = $e->getMessage();
       }catch(\ValidationException $e){
           // handle exceptions related to response from the server.
           $this->logger->info($e->getMessage()." with ");
           if(stristr($e->getMessage(),"Authorization"))
           {
               $inbox->addCritical("NDHK Authorization Error",$e->getMessage());
           }
           $this->logger->info(print_r($e->getResponse(),true)."");
           $method_data['errors'] = $e->getErrors();
       }catch(\Exception $e)
       { // handled common exception messages which will not get caught above.
           $method_data['errors'][] = $e->getMessage();
           $this->logger->info('Error While Creating Order : ' . $e->getMessage());
       }
   }
   else
   {
       $this->logger->info('Order with ID $orderId not found. Quitting :-(');
   }

                }
                }
   ```
2. Created two controllers 
   **1. Redirect/index.php

   2. Response/index.php**

**Redirect/index**

```
class Index extends  \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $pageFactory;
     public function __construct(Context $context,PageFactory $pageFactory) {
        $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;

        parent::__construct($context);

    }

    public function execute()
    {
         return $this->pageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

**Response**

```
class Index extends  \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_objectmanager;
    protected $_checkoutSession;
    protected $_orderFactory;
    protected $urlBuilder;
    private $logger;
    protected $response;
    protected $config;
    protected $messageManager;
    protected $transactionRepository;
    protected $cart;
    protected $inbox;

    public function __construct( Context $context,
            Session $checkoutSession,
            OrderFactory $orderFactory,
            Logger $logger,
            ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
            Http $response,
            TransactionBuilder $tb,
             \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
             \Magento\AdminNotification\Model\Inbox $inbox,
             \Magento\Sales\Api\TransactionRepositoryInterface $transactionRepository
        ) {


        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
        $this->response = $response;
        $this->config = $scopeConfig;
        $this->transactionBuilder = $tb;
        $this->logger = $logger;                    
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->inbox = $inbox;
        $this->transactionRepository = $transactionRepository;
        $this->urlBuilder = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
                            ->get('Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
  //RESPONSE
}
}
```

**contents.phtml**

```
<div class='ndhk'>
    <div class='errors'>
        <?php if($this->getMessages()){ ?>
        <?php foreach($this->getMessages() as $message): ?>
        <div class='alert alert-danger'>
            <p style='color:red'>
                <?= $message ?>
            </p>
        </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php }else{ ?>

        <?php
            $alldata = $block->_prepareLayout();
            // print_r($alldata);
        ?>


        <div style="width:200px;margin:auto;margin-top:20px">
            <img style="width:100%" src="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('NDHK_PaymentGateway::images/spinner.gif'); ?>">
            <center>Redirecting you to NDHK Payment Gateway</center>
        </div>
        <form name='ndhkpaymentredirect' method="post" action='<?= $alldata['actionUrl']; ?>'>
            <input type='hidden' name='login' value='<?= $alldata['login']; ?>'>
            <input type='hidden' name='pass' value='<?= $alldata['pass']; ?>'>
            <input type='hidden' name='amt' value='<?= $alldata['amt']; ?>'>
            <input type='hidden' name='txnid' value='<?= $alldata['txnid']; ?>'>
            <input type='hidden' name='txncurr' value='<?= $alldata['txncurr']; ?>'>
            <input type='hidden' name='signature' value='<?= $alldata['signature']; ?>'>
            <input type='hidden' name='date' value='<?= $alldata['date']; ?>'>
            <input type='hidden' name='ru' value='<?= $alldata['ru']; ?>'>
            <input type='hidden' name='od' value='<?= $alldata['od']; ?>'>
        </form>
        <script>
            document.ndhkpaymentredirect.submit();
        </script>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>

</div>
```

** view/frontend/layout/ndhk_redirect_index.xml **

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block cacheable="false"  name='ndhk_block' class="NDHK\PaymentGateway\Block\Main" template="NDHK_PaymentGateway::contents.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Problem**

Whenever I click on place order it takes me to ndhk/redirect and shows me the page in contents.phtml but it doesnot redirect me to payment gateway provider as written in contents.phtml and after sometime it redirects to homepage.

I do not know where i am doing wrong or what I should try.

Kindly help me if anyone.